# Finding deprecated methods and classed on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, deprecated, backwards-compatibility

Is there a way to set eclipse to warn you when you are using deprecated methods and classed on Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse by default warns you on deprecation. If not,

Right-click on your project and go to Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings. Click Enable project specific settings and then unfold Deprecated and restricted API and select appropriate value.